# Integrating Over a Product of (Non-Separable) Piecewise Functions (Hyper-Solid Angle of a Convex Polyhedral Cone)

Tags: integration, geometry, numerical-methods, polyhedra, solid-angle

My problem is as follows: given a function $f:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ where $n$ is some integer of order 10 and $f$ is defined by a product of (non-separable) linear piecewise functions, find the surface area of the polytope projected on the unit $n-1$-sphere. That is, find the (hyper)solid angle of a convex polyhedral cone defined by $f$, which is itself defined by $f(\vec{x}) = 1$ inside a particular convex polyhedral cone, and $0$ elsewhere (generalizing the formulae to calculate the solid angle of a convex polyhedral cone is something I have not yet tried, but I imagine it is difficult). Thus, if I project $f$ onto the $n-1$ dimensional hypersphere and integrate over the surface of the hypersphere, I should get the value I desire. I could also integrate over the $n$-dimensional unit ball, divide by the volume of the $n$-dimensional unit ball, and multiply by the surface area of the $n-1$ dimensional hypersphere. This would give an equivalent solution because the convex cone is both right and centered at the origin.

My approach so far has been to calculate the volume of the intersection of the cone and the unit ball, if only because integrating directly over the hypersphere requires either a change of coordinates or a non-trivial substition, both of which complicate matters.

Unfortunately, I don't think I can abandon the function $f$ entirely and simply integrate $1$ over the appropriate regions, because the region is difficult to determine, even in the case of only three defining inequalities - changing to spherical coordinates ends up requiring integrating very nasty things.

How does one go about integrating a piecewise function that is not easily separable over either a ball or a sphere? Is there some straightforward way I am missing to integrate such functions, or am I stuck using numerics? I do have numerical results, and I even have an analytical result for this particular cone (using spherical geometry result), but for higher-dimensional cases, the function becomes very sparsely supported and numerics get more and more difficult.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that your function $f$ is a product of indicator functions $g_i$, with each $g_i$ depending on an inequality? If you can partition $g_i$ so that one subset of $g_i$ has a specific variable on one side, and the other $g_i$ do not refer to that variable, then the subset simply defines the integration range(s) along that variable (and you can omit the subset from the product function $f$). A dependency graph (or use matrix) of the variables (coordinate axes) in $g_i$ would tell if this helps..

Comment: If I am understanding you correctly, then yes, that is the case. Can you go into a little bit more detail about a dependency graph or use matrix? If they are what I think they are, they would be useful if my region of integration was over a Cartesian hypercube, but because I am trying to integrate over a hypersphere, I think that complicates matters.

Comment: Another option (unless I'm just restating what you're already doing) is to integrate function $h(\hat{x})$ over the $n-1$ unit sphere, where $h(\hat{x}) = 1$ if the line $\vec{p}=t\hat{x}$ intersects the polytope at some $t \gt 0$, and $0$ otherwise. However, instead of defining $h$ as a product of Heaviside step functions of a linear combination of $x_i$, you define it as the intersection of halfspaces. In essence, convert the inequalities to hyperplanes defining the same inequality. You mentioned the inequalities were linear wrt. $x_i$, so that should be possible.

Comment: I don't think that's already what I'm doing, but how does one go about finding out if it intersects the polytope at some point? The convex cone is already defined as the intersection of half-spaces, but the trouble it's hard to find the region defined by those half-spaces. How does one go about testing if a line enters that region or not?

Comment: You rotate the coordinate system, with origin at the origin of the ray, so that the ray is along some positive coordinate axis. The polytope coordinates on that axis can then be ignored, because they do not affect whether or not the ray intersects the polytope. The problem reduces to finding out whether the origin is within the convex polytope (sans one dimension).

Comment: By the way, if you go with Monte Carlo integration (say, casting $n$-dimensional unit rays to the positive subspace (all coordinates positive), with the convex polytope suitably positioned), I suspect that working out the rotation would be wasted effort. Instead, you can do a binary search (starting with a range that must wholly include the convex polytope, no matter the direction) to some limit; the limit you can work out from the number of rays you intend to cast (since that determines the reliability/precision of the solid angle result). Your point-in-polytope inclusion test is **fast**.

Comment: I think there may be some miscommunication here - the convex polytope (in this case, a convex polyhedral cone) has a point at the origin, so asking whether or not the origin is in the convex polytope is trivial, because the polytope is partially defined by the origin. 


EDIT: As for the Monte Carlo comment - I'm not quite sure I understand what you mean by casting $n$-dimensional unit rays. Are you saying that I should take unit rays and throw them in the subspace randomly and see which ones fall in the polytope? I'm already doing that - how do I include the binary search there?

Comment: The test is *whether the origin is within the rotated coordinate system, ignoring one coordinate axis*, the one parallel to the ray. (But.. if you consider a cone-shaped object, with apex at origin, then doesn't it cover the full solid angle at origin, because origin is within the cone? If we ignore that infinitesimal point at origin, my test does apply, because we are rotating the coordinate system around the apex point.)

Comment: Wrt. binary search: well, you could instead consider the "ray" test as testing points along the ray at intervals of $\Delta$.

Comment: Have you tried to find the vertices of the convex polytope? I do not know how many subfunctions $g_i$ you have (and how complicated they are to convert to halfspaces -- if linear, should not be a problem). Projecting the vertices to a hypersphere, and estimating the solid angle as the solid angle of their convex hull on the hypersphere, might be easier. Since the cone is narrow, the hypersphere surface is not too curved, and errors due to edges not being projected exactly right should be small.

Comment: The vertices of the convex polytope are known. In fact, my goal is to find the solid angle of the convex hull on the hypersphere - but I don't know of any easy way to do so. The object here is basically a cone with a base of some arbitrary number of sides, but it has it's origin at the origin of the space. I still think I'm not understanding what you're getting at, so my simple example is this - have a pyramid, with the top vertex at the origin, and with some arbitrary base points (in the first octant). Find the solid angle subtended by the top vertex.

Comment: How many vertices? How many subfunctions $g_i$? (The issue wrt. the cone apex at origin: Here, the observer point is at origin. If you have a vertex at origin, it means the vertex overlaps the observer, and therefore, technically in some sense, it covers the observer, and thus the entire solid angle the observer can observe. If you exclude the zero-volume point at origin, then the observer can see the rest of the convex polytope. It's that insignificant a detail.)

Comment: In the pyramid case, it could have as few as three vertices and as many as $n$, where $n$ is an arbitrary number. The subfunctions $g_i$ are just those that represent the half-planes that slice up $R^3$ to define this region, so there would be $n$ such functions $g_i$. Note that this is only the case in 3 dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer, but expands on a comment I made to the question.
First, some background.

Let's assume function $f$ is a product of $k$ subfunctions $g$, in $n$ variables,
$$f(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n) = \prod_{i=1}^{k} g_i(x_1,\dots,x_n)$$
where each subfunction $g_i$ is 
$$g_i(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n) = H \left ( c_{i,0} + \sum_{j=1}^{n} c_{i,j} x_j \right )$$
where $H(x)$ denotes the [Heaviside step function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function),
$$H(x) = \begin{cases}
0, & x \lt 0 \\
1, & x \ge 0
\end{cases}$$
As to the notation, one could write
$$f(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n) = \prod_{i=1}^{k} H\left(c_{i,0} + \sum_{j=1}^{n} c_{i,j} x_j \right )$$

---

Let's consider subfunction $i$:
$$g_i(x_1,\dots,x_n) = H\left(c_{i,0} + \sum_{j=1}^{n} c_{i,j} x_j \right)$$
If we assume an inequality evaluates to $1$ if true, and to $0$ if false, we can write the above as
$$g_i(x_1,\dots,x_n) = \left( c_{i,0} + \sum_{j=1}^{n} c_{i,j} x_j \ge 0 \right)$$
If $c_{i,m} \gt 0$ for some $m$, $1 \le m \le n$, we can reorder the inequality to
$$g_i(x_1,\dots,x_n) = \left( x_m \le \frac{c_{i,0} + \sum_{j=1,j\ne m}^{n} c_{i,j} x_j}{c_{i,m}} \right)$$
If $c_{i,m} \lt 0$, to
$$g_i(x_1,\dots,x_n) = \left( x_m \ge \frac{c_{i,0} + \sum_{j=1,j\ne m}^{n} c_{i,j} x_j}{c_{i,m}} \right)$$

Now, if we intend to calculate some integral
$$\int\dots\int_{R^n} f(x_1,\dots,x_n) dx_1 \dots dx_n$$
we can replace all subfunctions $g_i$ for which $c_{i,m} \ne 0$, with $1$, by changing the integration interval for $x_m$ from $[-\infty,\infty]$ to one or more ranges specified by the above inequalities. If there is more than one range for some $x_m$, the ranges must not overlap.

It might look like we could do that recursively to eliminate all subfunctions, but that may not be the case, since **the limits for each integral can only refer to outer integrals' variables**. This is what I called, offhand, as "dependency graph" in my comment.

Basically, if matrix $c_{i,j}$ can be made triangular by reordering rows and/or reodering columns, we can replace all subfunctions with 1 by setting the integration intervals. ($c_{i,j}$ is what I called, again very offhand, the "use matrix". Perhaps coefficient matrix would have been more appropriate; apologies.)

---

Note that I am not a mathematician; I only use math as a tool for finding solutions to whatever problems I encounter. So, the original comment, and this explanation of the comment, is just the approach I'd use in trying to find a solution for the original problem (too complex integrals to evaluate).

Also, I might be completely wrong and on the wrong track, too.

Perhaps mentioning Heaviside step function in the question might tickle the resident mathematicians enough to lend their brains to the problem at hand?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That definitely is a helpful technique to organize the inequalities. Also, I think there's a typo in your reordering of inequalities - there should be a minus sign on the left for your $c_{i,m} > 0$ case. But that's no problem.

This is fine if I was integrating over a rectangular surface, however the problem gets significantly harder when integrating over the surface (or interior) of a ball. Perhaps I can change variables to hyperspherical coordinates, but then the integrand ends up being *very* complicated very quickly.

Comment: @SamBlitz: I replaced the minus sign by changing $\ge$ to $\le$. But yes, this was just an explanation/expansion of the comment I made, and not intended as an answer to your question. (I often have to do these kinds of explorations myself to find a method to solve the problems myself; I hope I didn't waste your time too much with this.)

Comment: No, I appreciated the exploration! Unfortunately, this problem seems "hard," so I've resolved myself to do this numerically, at least until I can figure out how to generalize the geometric solution to this problem. That is, unless someone can provide an answer that helps me out here!

Comment: At ten dimensions, you're already well into the domain where [Monte Carlo integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_integration) is well applied. I wouldn't be too surprised if numerical calculation is the only practical one, as radiation detector math (the solid angle covered by a flat detector, when the source is not a point but a volume) gets seriously wonky even in 3D, and numerical solutions are already more practical.

Comment: I think that's fair - the trouble is, at high dimensions, the region of interest is so small that Monte Carlo integration becomes a task in generating enough points that at least one falls into the range. In my most recent calculation, which involves a 15-dimensional cone defined by some inequalities (assuming it wasn't trivially zero due to some mistake on my part), even after searching 10,000,000 randomly placed points, I found none that were on the projected region of the polygon. Even in the 7 dimensional case (which I worked out), I ended up with a "solid angle" of the order 10^-4.

Comment: @SamBlitz: Since the object is convex, you could use a lattice/grid walker (in hyper-solid angle coordinates) to find the lattice cells that span the boundary. The "inside" part contains the lattice cells fully within the convex cone, and are easy to count (flood fill in $N$ dimensions). To refine the estimate, you only need to subdivide the edge cells. (In 10 dimensions, each cell subdivides typically into $2^{10}$ subcells, so this subdivision will be slow, though.) Pretty similar to a isosurface walker I showed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30429480/1475978).

Comment: Make that (flood fill in $N-1$ dimensions), since the lattice/grid is in hyper-solid angle coordinates; i.e. on the surface of the hypersphere. Of course, you could find the $N$-dimensional voxels that are on the surface of the original object, and use the voxel map to estimate the solid angle. But, even just 8 samples along each of 10 dimensions means you have $8^{10} = 1,073,741,824$ cells. No, looking at the numbers, the lattice/grid approach just needs too much memory!

Comment: Right, one issue is memory, definitely. The first calculation I did was 7 dimensional, and that one, while it required a lot of points, still generated a reasonable approximation. At 15 dimensions, I'm having trouble finding a single point at random that works. I may need to rethink the problem.